# Data from Android Notification of WhatsApp or any other Application

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to take data of **whatsapp message** coming in my Android from Notification bar Is it possible to get this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a service to listen to incoming notifications by extending `NotificationListenerService`  in which, you'll have a method call back  :

```
@Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) { .... }
```

Where you'll get all the data inside that particular notification.

If you want only WhatsApp Notifications, you can add a filter
 which matches the package name like: `sbn.getPackageName().matches("com.whatsapp")`

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.html) is more information about StatusBarNotification

for getting the title/content(message) of the notifications you'll need to extract them from the bundle    `Bundle bundle = statusBarNotification.getNotification().extras;` you can extract message from the bundle using something like this:

```
private String getDataFromBundle(Bundle bundle) {
        Object data = bundle.get("android.bigText");
        if (data == null) {
            data = bundle.get("android.text");
        }
        return data == null? "" :data.toString();
    }
```

PS: don't forget to register your service in manifest..

Comment: You should include how to also get the MESSAGE; as he said. And isn't there a required permission for this?

Comment: @AbAppletic no, you don't need any particular permissions but you do need to register an intent filter in the manifest : <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />  for your service....

Comment: removed downvote and replaced it with +1. But edit the question and include the intent filter and include in which activity should it be applied to in the manifest.

Comment: Guys can you further elobrate it i cant get it clearly thanks in advance :)